# How to interrupt a thread with future, want to perform some task by the interruption issued by future

Tags: java, multithreading, future, cancellation, interrupted-exception

I am new to future and multithreading in java. I have a simple problem which has turned out to be complex, I have a number of threads (all have open sessions in them) which are open infinitely. Whenever one thread throws a custom exception (a timeout exception on the session), I have to interrupt all the threads and close all sessions gracefully. What I do is that I store the future objects returned by the threads (in an ArrayList) and loop through it and issue future.cancel for all when one thread throws an exception.

```
private static void futureCancel()
{
        for(int i=0;i<numberStreams;i++)
        {
            Future<String> future=futureList.get(i);
            try{
                future.cancel(true);
                future.get();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("In interrupted block!");
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
        return;
    }
```

The issue here is that I cannot add InterruptedException in my thread code due to some requirement issues and the way things work on the other side of the sessions. If I throw an InterruptedException from my callable, it does not reach the catch block specified above. Incase I add sleep in my thread (ok for testing) and handle the InterruptedException, it enters that block as soon as future.cancel is issued. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Futuer#cancel(boolean)` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) states

> This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has already
>   been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If
>   successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this
>   task should never run. If the task has already started, then the
>   mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread
>   executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the
>   task.

So either the `ExecutorService` hasn't executed the `Runnable`/`Callable` and can remove it from its queue or it has and the `ExecutorService` has to call `Thread#interrupt()` and your `Runnable`/`Callable` code has to handle it.

There's no other way through the `Future` interface to interrupt a thread. If your `Runnable` doesn't have a way to handle interrupts, then a number of things can happen. If an `InterruptedException` occurs, it will bubble up to the `ExecutorService` and be wrapped in a `ExecutionException` that will be thrown from `Future#get()`. If no `InterruptedException` occurs in the thread executing the `Runnable`, your `Runnable` will continue unhindered.

You should really consider changing your `Runnable` to handle interrupts.

Comment: I understand that my Runnable/Callable code has to handle it "InterruptedException". I cannot add a thread.sleep, object.wait or have a blockingqueue or something in the Runnable/Callable code, is there a way I can still add code to handle the InterruptedException?

Comment: @AnujaKhemka No, your code has to actually support interruption. See the official [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis , this will really help em clarify the doubts I have about future.

Comment: Just to be clear, `call()` can throw an `InterruptedException`.  `run()` cannot @AnujaKhemka.

Answer (score 1):

> If I throw an InterruptedException from my callable, it does not reach the catch block specified above.

It won't.  The `InterruptedException` catch block around the `future.get()` is when the thread that is *calling* the get gets interrupted -- not your `Callable`.

If your `Callable` is interrupted and throws `InterruptedException` then when you call `get()` it will enter the `ExecutionException` and the `e.getCause()` should be `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Thanks! Made my understanding a lot clearer on future cancel. Unfortunately, as specified below, I guess I will ahve to explicitly handle "InterruptedException" in the Runnable/Callable code.

Comment: No problem.  You don't have to handle `InterruptedException` in `call()` because it can throw @AnujaKhemka.  You do have to handle it in `run()`.